# Special relativity - 2 astronauts syncronize their clocks and moves in different paths at different velocities, which clocks is left behind? and why?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time-dilation

i have the following problem and I'm not understanding if my strategy to solve it is correct:
Two astronauts synchronize their clocks starting at time zero from the origin $O$ of an inertial reference frame S. They simultaneously reach point A:{ $x_A=d, y_A=0$}.
The first astronaut moved in a straight line at constant speed $v=\frac{c \pi}{4}$ while the second travelled at constant velocity (in absolute value) over a semicircle in the $xy$ plane of diameter $d$. Upon their meeting, the astronauts notice a 1 year difference between their clocks. Which clock is left behind, and why?
Which value has d?

Now, I've write down the Lorentz transformations

$x'=\gamma(ct-\beta x)$

$ct'=\gamma(x-\beta ct)$

And then i substitute $x'=d$, $\beta=\frac{\frac{\pi c}{4}}{c}$, $x=dcos\theta$ and because of the first reference frame reach the point $d$ and the second reach the point $x=dcos\theta$

$d=\gamma(ct-\frac{\frac{\pi c}{4}}{c} d cos \theta)$

$0=\gamma(d cos \theta-\frac{\frac{\pi c}{4}}{c} ct)$

And i get from the second $d=\frac{\pi}{4}ct$. It's correct? how i could properly say which clock is left befind? I think that the one that travels in a straight line needs more time to reach the same point,cause the straight line in the Minkowski space maximize the time. Anyone can help me?

Comment: What is the source of this exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the Lorentz transformation. It translates coordinates between two different inertial coordinate systems. There's only one relevant coordinate system in this problem: the one with respect to which it was specified.

Work out the elapsed proper time for the two astronauts (distance over speed times gamma) as a function of $d$, set the difference to 1 year, and solve for  $d$. You're right that the first one has the longer elapsed time.

Comment: How i could evaluate the gamma factor for the second astronaut if the velocity of the second astronaut is unknown? imposing that the second astronaut runs over a semicircle and arrives simultaneously i get that the velocity is $c\frac{\pi^2}{8}$ that is greater than c. What i should do?

Comment: @user251479 I think it must be a mistake. If $cπ/4$ is the speed on the semicircle then it makes sense. (The words speed and velocity are backwards also.)

Comment: Which is the speed of the non inertial observer? Could you help me to find it? I get a speed greater than C, how it's possible?